# Design pattern for "Read, Process, Save" pattern?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I'm looking for a desing pattern to solve the following:

Read an Input

Process the data (inc validation)

Save the result

Examples would be:
Read a csv file, process the data, save as xml
Read an MQ message, process the data, save to database.

I was thinking of a BusinessObject that:

- Has an `IInput` implementation to handle reading and loading itself.
- Can be validated through "rules"
- Has an `IOutput` implementation to handle saving itself.

e.g. (pseudo code!)

```
public abstract class BusinessObject
    {
        public IInput Input { get; set; }
        public IOutput Output { get; set; }

        public BusinessObject(IInput input, IOutput output)
        { }
    }
```

and then have a Load, Process and Save method.

However, it doesn't seem right to me.  I *think*  the BO should be capable of loading and saving itself?

If anyone knows what pattern this might be so I can read up on it, or give me an example/explanation I would be very grateful.

Comment: Just fyi, you might found more information under the topic "ETL" or extract-transform-load.

Comment: As far as business objects knowing how to load and save themselves, I think that's one of those topics where there are two schools of thought - one for, and one against. Sounds like perhaps something similar to the unit of work pattern may be relevant to you as well.

Comment: @JustinPinkley Half of me thinks that I should have factory classes that use an input to create a BO, then another set that take a BO and write out the result.  The other half says that the BO should be capable of loading and saving itself, given the means to do so.

Comment: Some thoughts on BO's knowing how to load and save themselves (i.e smart objects) vs Repository pattern :  http://stackoverflow.com/q/888911/184774

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could potentially use the Pipeline pattern. In that pattern, you define a chain of components (pipeline components; the chain is then the pipeline) and you feed it input data. Every pipeline component is then executed in turn on the data that is being pushed through the pipe. Any component can read data from and write data to that data.

See also:

- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38799/Pipeline-and-Yield-in-C.
- [C# -Pipeline Style event model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1316254/c-sharp-pipeline-style-event-model)
- http://rantdriven.com/post/Simple-Pipe-and-Filters-Implementation-in-C-with-Fluent-Interface-Behavior.aspx

Comment: Pipeline seems exactly what I want.  Not sure I even need a BO at all with this, just my filters: load, validate, process, validate result, save :)